# Why does NuGet think my packages are installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

NuGet never seems to work for me.  Once I check my code into source control, and then try and download it on a different computer and click Build Solution, it always fails to automatically restore NuGet packages.

I then manually follow the steps on the NuGet docs, https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

and https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore

However, I discover my Package Restore seems to be configured correctly.

What's super frustrating about this is that when I right click on the Solution and click Restore NuGet Packages in Visual Studio 2015, the Output window doesn't display anything NuGet is doing behind the scenes.  I cannot tell if it's even hitting the NuGet Proxy I set-up at myget.org.

What else can I try?

Here is an example Package Manager Console session, where NuGet completely screws things up when I try to follow the manual, console-driven steps to fix everything:

```
PM> Update-Package -Reinstall Antlr
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'AdminApi', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'Antlr 3.4.1.9004' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Antlr 3.4.1.9004' from AdminApi
Package 'Antlr.3.4.1.9004' already exists in folder 'd:\projects\Tools\AdminRoot\Admin\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Antlr 3.4.1.9004' does not exist in project 'AdminApi'
Package 'Antlr 3.4.1.9004' already exists in folder 'd:\projects\Tools\AdminRoot\Admin\packages'
Update-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Antlr3.Runtime'.At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -Reinstall Antlr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.Updat 
   ePackageCommand
```

Comment: I believe this problem happens with nested solutions.